# How to insert multiple rows of a datatable into a table in database at once using mysql,c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datatable

How to insert multiple rows of a datatable into a table in database at once using MySQL, in C#

```
string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
using(var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)) {
     foreach(DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns) {
      bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
     }

     bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
     bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
     bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

I tried this but getting error-login failed for user '`testuser`'.This is the db credential

Comment: i tried this but getting error-login failed for user 'testuser'.This is the db credential

Comment: You are using `SqlBulkCopy` meant for `SQL Server` but you have tagged question for `MySQL`. Which database server are you using?

Comment: Please be more specific. Your code does not have anything to say for **login failed for user**. It is far before this data copying work to happen.

Comment: am using mysql..is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`SqlBulkCopy` is for Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle's MySQL Connector/NET doesn't have any bulk copy functionality. [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) is an alternative MySQL driver for .NET that does support bulk copy (in `MySqlBulkCopy`) in the latest beta version, as per [this documentation](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysql-bulk-copy/).

You will first need to uninstall MySql.Data, then install MySqlConnector. It uses the same class names, so it should be a drop-in upgrade.

```cs
string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    using (var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection)
    {
        // ColumnMappings isn't current supported, but they will be inferred automatically
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
        await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
    }
}
```